# How to wrap Express Middleware with a base Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

How to wrap Express middleware in a common middleware? For instance if I want to log to New Relic and do some logging in all middleware.

```
const newRelic = require('newrelic');
require('colors');

function BaseMiddleware(wrappedMiddleware) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    newRelic.setTransactionName('middleware', wrappedMiddleware.name);
    console.log(`middleware: ${wrappedMiddleware.name} run`.green);

    return wrappedMiddleware(req, res, next);
  };
}

module.exports = BaseMiddleware;
```

And then..in another middleware file:

```
module.exports = BaseMiddleware(myCustomMiddleware);
```

This is not triggering correctly thought. It seems like it is in an endless loop.

Comment: "It seems like it is in an endless loop" - is it in an endless loop? Are there any error messages?

Comment: There are no error messages. It just keeps refreshing over and over.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your browser app, not the express middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this on my local machine:

```
function BaseMiddleware(wrappedMiddleware) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`middleware: ${wrappedMiddleware.name} run`);
    return wrappedMiddleware(req, res, next);
  };
}

function mw(req, res, next) {
  console.log('inside mw');
  next();
}

app.use(BaseMiddleware(mw));
```

And it all ran through correctly, with it logging correctly:

```
middleware: mw run
inside mw
```

Comment: Yea i think this is some error in the application code actually. Seems to work for me on fresh install too.